# How to install waf naxsi with a nginx system on linux mint

Tags: linux, nginx, linux-mint

I have installed nginx and running OK.
But I have problem to install naxsi.
some article says that

> But if we want some extra modules, such as naxsi or
>   perhaps the HTTP upload module, we actually need to recompile Nginx
>   with those modules.

but I don't know how to do that. please help me :)

Comment: Did you find a way to do it without reinstalling? I want to add naxsi and i am stuck.

Comment: this is tutorial that I found in Bahasa Indonesia
http://codecrosser.blogspot.co.id/2015/09/instalasi-dan-konfigurasi-nginx-web.html